# Message (the application may be doing too much work on its main thread) while viewing API data inside a LazyColumn

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, retrofit2, kotlin-coroutines

I'm trying to set retrieved data from an API into a LazyColumn, which will be called every time a date is picked from a Material3 date picker, but during the app, these warning traces (#1, #2) in Logcat appeared in every API call. Although I make it inside a LaunchedEffect, The app sometimes takes too much time (up to 15 seconds) in every API call.

I've attached some code samples for more explanation.

```
@Composable
fun TodayMatchesByLeague(matchesList: List<TodayResponseItem?>) {
    LazyColumn {
        items(matchesList.size) {
            TodayMatchItem(matchItem)
        }
    }
}
```

```
@Composable
fun FetchTodayGamesData(
    mainViewModel: MainViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
    val date = mainViewModel.dialogueDate.observeAsState().value!!
    if (mainViewModel.isClicked.value!!) {
        LaunchedEffect(key1 = null) {
            mainViewModel.getTodayMatches(
                date, 2023
            )
            mainViewModel.saveCalendarClicked(false)
        }
    }
    when (val state =
        mainViewModel.todayMatchesState.collectAsState().value
    ) {
        is TodayMatchesState.Empty -> {}
        is TodayMatchesState.Loading -> {}
        is TodayMatchesState.Error -> {}
        is TodayMatchesState.Success -> {
            TodayMatchesByLeague(
                matchesList = state.data.body()!!.response!!
            )
        }
    }
}
```

```
//
val selectedDate = rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf<LocalDate?>(LocalDate.now()) }
val localDate = selectedDate.value
viewModel.saveDialogueDate(localDate.toString())
val datePickerState = rememberDatePickerState()
var sheetState by remember{ mutableStateOf(false) }
val selectedDate1 = Instant.ofEpochMilli(datePickerState.selectedDateMillis ?: 0)
          .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
          .toLocalDate()

if (datePickerState.selectedDateMillis != null) {
          selectedDate.value = selectedDate1
          viewModel.saveCalendarClicked(true)
}

if (sheetState)
          BottomSheetDatePicker(
                state = datePickerState,
                onDismissRequest = { sheetState = false }
          )
IconButton(
          onClick = {
                sheetState = true
          }
) {
          Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.CalendarMonth, contentDescription = "Calendar")
}
```

```
//ViewModel
@HiltViewModel
class MainViewModel @Inject constructor(private val matchesRepository: MatchesRepository): ViewModel() {

    private var _todayMatchesState = MutableStateFlow<TodayMatchesState>(TodayMatchesState.Empty)
    val todayMatchesState: StateFlow<TodayMatchesState> = _todayMatchesState

    //Calendar Dialogue Date
    private var _dialogueDate = MutableLiveData("")
    val dialogueDate: LiveData<String> = _dialogueDate
    private var _isClicked = MutableLiveData(true)
    val isClicked: LiveData<Boolean> = _isClicked

    fun saveCalendarClicked(isClicked: Boolean) {
        _isClicked.value = isClicked
    }

    fun saveDialogueDate(date: String) {
        _dialogueDate.value = date
    }

    fun getTodayMatches(date: String, season: Int) {
        _todayMatchesState.value = TodayMatchesState.Loading

        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {

            try {
                val todayMatchesResponse = matchesRepository.getTodayMatches(date, season)
                _todayMatchesState.value = TodayMatchesState.Success(todayMatchesResponse)
            }
            catch (exception: HttpException) {
                _todayMatchesState.value = TodayMatchesState.Error("Something went wrong")
            }
            catch (exception: IOException) {
                _todayMatchesState.value = TodayMatchesState.Error("No internet connection")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#1

```
Event:APP_SCOUT_WARNING Thread:main backtrace:
    at java.lang.Thread.currentThread(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal.get(ThreadLocal.java:162)
    at android.os.Looper.myLooper(Looper.java:323)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.android.HandlerContext.isDispatchNeeded(HandlerDispatcher.kt:137)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTaskKt.dispatch(DispatchedTask.kt:160)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.dispatchResume(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:474)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.resumeImpl(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:508)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.resumeImpl$default(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:497)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.resumeWith(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:368)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.StateFlowSlot.makePending(StateFlow.kt:284)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.StateFlowImpl.updateState(StateFlow.kt:349)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.StateFlowImpl.setValue(StateFlow.kt:316)
    at coil.compose.ConstraintsSizeResolver.measure-3p2s80s(AsyncImage.kt:209)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.BackwardsCompatNode.measure-3p2s80s(BackwardsCompatNode.kt:312)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.measure-BRTryo0(LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.kt:186)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.SizeNode.measure-3p2s80s(Size.kt:838)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.measure-BRTryo0(LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.kt:186)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.PaddingNode.measure-3p2s80s(Padding.kt:397)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.measure-BRTryo0(LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.kt:186)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$performMeasureBlock$1.invoke(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:255)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$performMeasureBlock$1.invoke(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:254)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.Snapshot$Companion.observe(Snapshot.kt:488)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver$ObservedScopeMap.observe(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:501)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:257)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:133)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeMeasureSnapshotReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:113)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.performMeasure-BRTryo0(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:1622)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.access$performMeasure-BRTryo0(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:39)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$MeasurePassDelegate.remeasure-BRTryo0(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:623)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$MeasurePassDelegate.measure-BRTryo0(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:599)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.RowColumnMeasurementHelper.measureWithoutPlacing-_EkL_-Y(RowColumnMeasurementHelper.kt:120)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.RowColumnMeasurePolicy.measure-3p2s80s(RowColumnImpl.kt:69)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerNodeCoordinator.measure-BRTryo0(InnerNodeCoordinator.kt:134)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.PaddingNode.measure-3p2s80s(Padding.kt:397)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.measure-BRTryo0(LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.kt:186)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$performMeasureBlock$1.invoke(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:255)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$performMeasureBlock$1.invoke(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:254)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.Snapshot$Companion.observe(Snapshot.kt:488)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver$ObservedScopeMap.observe(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:501)
```

#2

```
Event:APP_SCOUT_HANG Thread:main backtrace:
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$SinkHolder.-$$Nest$sfgetfinalize_count(Unknown Source:2)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference.reachabilityFence(Reference.java:342)
    at libcore.util.NativeAllocationRegistry.registerNativeAllocation(NativeAllocationRegistry.java:281)
    at android.graphics.ColorFilter.getNativeInstance(ColorFilter.java:68)
    at android.graphics.Paint.getNativeInstance(Paint.java:738)
    at android.graphics.BaseRecordingCanvas.drawBitmap(BaseRecordingCanvas.java:95)
    at androidx.compose.ui.graphics.AndroidCanvas.drawImageRect-HPBpro0(AndroidCanvas.android.kt:275)
    at androidx.compose.ui.graphics.drawscope.CanvasDrawScope.drawImage-AZ2fEMs(CanvasDrawScope.kt:257)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeDrawScope.drawImage-AZ2fEMs(Unknown Source:24)
    at androidx.compose.ui.graphics.drawscope.DrawScope.drawImage-AZ2fEMs$default(DrawScope.kt:566)
    at androidx.compose.ui.graphics.vector.DrawCache.drawInto(DrawCache.kt:102)
    at androidx.compose.ui.graphics.vector.VectorComponent.draw(Vector.kt:181)
    at androidx.compose.ui.graphics.vector.VectorPainter.onDraw(VectorPainter.kt:248)
    at androidx.compose.ui.graphics.painter.Painter.draw-x_KDEd0(Painter.kt:212)
    at androidx.compose.ui.draw.PainterNode.draw(PainterModifier.kt:342)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeDrawScope.drawDirect-x_KDEd0$ui_release(LayoutNodeDrawScope.kt:105)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeDrawScope.draw-x_KDEd0$ui_release(LayoutNodeDrawScope.kt:86)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.drawContainedDrawModifiers(NodeCoordinator.kt:376)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.draw(NodeCoordinator.kt:365)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.performDraw(LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.kt:265)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.drawContainedDrawModifiers(NodeCoordinator.kt:373)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.draw(NodeCoordinator.kt:365)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.draw$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:962)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerNodeCoordinator.performDraw(InnerNodeCoordinator.kt:183)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeDrawScope.drawContent(LayoutNodeDrawScope.kt:66)
    at androidx.compose.material.ripple.AndroidRippleIndicationInstance.drawIndication(Ripple.android.kt:270)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.IndicationModifier.draw(Indication.kt:346)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.BackwardsCompatNode.draw(BackwardsCompatNode.kt:350)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeDrawScope.drawDirect-x_KDEd0$ui_release(LayoutNodeDrawScope.kt:105)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeDrawScope.performDraw(LayoutNodeDrawScope.kt:76)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeDrawScope.drawContent(LayoutNodeDrawScope.kt:55)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.BackgroundNode.draw(Background.kt:159)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeDrawScope.drawDirect-x_KDEd0$ui_release(LayoutNodeDrawScope.kt:105)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeDrawScope.draw-x_KDEd0$ui_release(LayoutNodeDrawScope.kt:86)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.drawContainedDrawModifiers(NodeCoordinator.kt:376)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.access$drawContainedDrawModifiers(NodeCoordinator.kt:56)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator$drawBlock$1$1.invoke(NodeCoordinator.kt:395)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator$drawBlock$1$1.invoke(NodeCoordinator.kt:394)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.Snapshot$Companion.observe(Snapshot.kt:488)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver$ObservedScopeMap.observe(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:501)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:257)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:133)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator$drawBlock$1.invoke(NodeCoordinator.kt:394)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure first that the API is not the bottlenck here. You can send a request to your API using [PostMan](https://www.postman.com/downloads/) or the [Thunderclient](https://www.thunderclient.com/) Visual Studio Code Plugin. With these tools, you can check whether the API itself needs that much time to return the response.

Once you sorted this out as a possible cause, I would suggest that you attach a [debugger](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug) and set a breakpoint to the code within the `LaunchedEffect`. I see no obvious error in your code, but some smells:

**1.)** `LaunchedEffect` or `viewModelScope` is redundant

You are using both a `viewModelScope` and a `LaunchedEffect` combined for calling the `getTodayMatches` function. If you use a `LaunchedEffect`, you can directly call a suspend function without the need for a `viewModelScope`. So you could update your ViewModel function like this:

```
suspend fun getTodayMatches(date: String, season: Int) {
    _todayMatchesState.value = TodayMatchesState.Loading

    try {
        val todayMatchesResponse = matchesRepository.getTodayMatches(date, season)
        _todayMatchesState.value = TodayMatchesState.Success(todayMatchesResponse)
    }
    catch (exception: HttpException) {
        _todayMatchesState.value = TodayMatchesState.Error("Something went wrong")
    }
    catch (exception: IOException) {
        _todayMatchesState.value = TodayMatchesState.Error("No internet connection")
    }
}
```

**2.)** Callback Handling seems odd

Once the DatePicker is confirmed, you set the `isClicked` variable in the ViewModel to true. Then you use a side effect on another place to execute code when the variable becomes true. Instead of this approach, I would suggest that you directly call the ViewModel function when the selected date changes.

```
var selectedDate by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf<LocalDate?>(LocalDate.now()) }
val datePickerState = rememberDatePickerState()
var sheetState by remember{ mutableStateOf(false) }

// Whenever selected date changes, call getTodayMatches
LaunchedEffect(datePickerState.selectedDateMillis) {
    if (datePickerState.selectedDateMillis != null) {
        // update state variable
        selectedDate = Instant.ofEpochMilli(datePickerState.selectedDateMillis ?: 0)
            .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
            .toLocalDate()
        viewModel.getTodayMatches(selectedDate.toString(), 2023)
    }
}

if (sheetState)

    BottomSheetDatePicker(
        // ...
    )
    // ...
}
```

**3.)** LazyColumn seems odd

It seems like you are mixing two overloads of the [`items`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/LazyListScope#items(kotlin.Int,kotlin.Function1,kotlin.Function1,kotlin.Function2)) function. You probably wanted to do

```
LazyColumn {
    items(matchesList) { matchItem ->
        TodayMatchItem(matchItem)
    }
}
```

**4.)** Single Source of Truth

It seems like you are having a lot of duplication in your Composable and ViewModel. Either store the date in your ViewModel, or store it in the Composable. But now, you have a `selectedDate` variable in your Composable, and also at the same time you have a `dialogueDate` in your ViewModel. And you need a lot of code to keep these two synchronized. In my suggestion above, I store the date in the Composable.